# RollupJS ES6 module can't get imported because of default not found for redux and redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, rollup

I have made a package for my login form that use `react-redux` and [redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/tree/v7.0.4/src/immutable).

Both `react-redux` and `redux-form` are peer dependencies.

- During the build of my rollup, I don't have any error message.
- When I try to import my package into a project I have:

> WARNING in ./node_modules/login-form/dist/login-form.es.js
>   7455:22-33 "export 'default' (imported as '_reactRedux') was not found in 'react-redux'
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/login-form/dist/login-form.es.js
>   7505:17-23 "export 'default' (imported as '_redux') was not found in 'redux'

*I have never imported myself `redux` in my login form project.*

- This is how I imported `redux-form` in my project:

  ```
  import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form/immutable';
  ```

This was bundled by rollup and that was present in my es module :

```
import _reactRedux from 'react-redux';
import _redux from 'redux';
```

I must have done something wrong, but I don't  know what.

This is the list of my rollup dependencies

```
"rollup": "^0.50.0",
"rollup-plugin-babel": "^3.0.2",
"rollup-plugin-cleanup": "^1.0.1",
"rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^8.2.1",
"rollup-plugin-inject": "^2.0.0",
"rollup-plugin-json": "^2.3.0",
"rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^3.0.0",
"rollup-plugin-replace": "^2.0.0",
"rollup-plugin-uglify": "^2.0.1",
"rollup-plugin-visualizer": "^0.3.1",
"rollup-watch": "^4.3.1",
```

Comment: It looks like this might be an [existing issue](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs/issues/185)? Just confirming what `rollup-plugin` are you using?

Comment: I've updated with my rollup deps version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to install it using in externals instead of 'redux-form' => 'redux-form-immutable'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 5.0.0+ you need to add the following in your config:

```
commonjs({
  namedExports: {
    // left-hand side can be an absolute path, a path
    // relative to the current directory, or the name
    // of a module in node_modules
    'node_modules/my-lib/index.js': [ 'named' ]
  }
})
```

Comment: I have tried to add this, but I couldn't get a line to work. Do you know exactly what to type ? I did this: `'./node_modules/redux-form/immutable.js': ['Field', 'reduxForm'],`

Comment: Also, I have tried to add this in my `login-form` rollup package, not in my webpack application.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be tied to the version of the commonjs package used / when this issue was raised.

In my case I used the latest version of `@rollup/plugin-commonjs` and namedExports are handled automatically.

I understand that since then the packages have been namespaced under @rollup.